# How to open a picture from Ubuntu server, via [SSH on] my laptop Macbook?

Tags: command-line, ssh, mac, photo

I am currently using Macbook iterm2 for ssh connection to my ubuntu server.
 I am image processing via terminal and want to open the result. What whould be easist way of doing this?

Comment: *The image file is on the server. If you want to view it locally (on laptop), you need a local copy.* **Are you unsure how to do that?**

Comment: @david6, could also view the image via network share using samba, sshfs, minidlna.

Comment: *Don't disagree.* However, it is not clear what method / approach is being asked about ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about mac, but in your ubuntu server you can enable forward X session. Afterwards you can run a graphical application on your server and relay the application window directly to your ssh client. I can describe the procedure for ubuntu serer AND client.

Server:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
*find line X11Forwarding and set it to yes*
```

**NOTE** server must have X11 installed for this to work (ubuntu server doesn't come with X11 on by default as I recall but you can install it yourself. Mind that it's a major change to your server that can severely load up your server if it's a low cost machine not suited for graphical interface)

Client:
run your ssh command with `-x` paramter. Afterwards you can request any graphics viewing software installed to open your picture.

```
user@remotehost# programofchoice /path/to/picture
```

**My suggestion**
A simpler way is probably to simply copy the file to local disk using scp (a secure copy that uses ssh to copy the file to the local disk - you make a simple script to download the file without typing the path every time.